# Supervisord - Supervisor exit status 255 not expected on A

Tags: linux, php, unix, supervisord, gearman

I have no clue why this always happened. I tried to reload the supervisord process but still doesnt the same error appears

The error show this..

[FATAL      Exited too quickly (process log may have details)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGep9.png)

and the supervisord.conf

[Supervisor config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbKlo.png)

Answer (score 0):

The job of Supervisord is to keep things running if they crash. In this case, Supervisord has detected your application has crashed, so it keeps trying to restart it.

Try running the application (in your case, as the Apache user). When you run the command, it should not go into the background.

Comment: previously I have read the issues that you say. seems like it didn't work. fyi I did this on sudo su. the problem is the status always show fatal and trying to start the gearman worker but its always failed